# TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined discord bot js say command

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

So I am making a discord bot and here the problem :

```js
if(cmd === `${prefix}say`){
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGE")) return message.reply("cant use this command");
    let botmessage = args.join(" ");
    message.delete().catch();
    message.channel.send(botmessage)
    for(var item=0; item<re.length; item++) 
    {}
```

and when I open the .bat to execute the bot it say : TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Comment: Can you show how you defined `args`?

Comment: let rUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));

Comment: that's the definition of `rUser` not `args`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define args first. And how did you define cmd? That doesn't look really convenenient if you have to put ${prefix} everytime in your command. You may want to change it aswell. Put this piece of code somewhere high up in your code

```
const prefix = "!";
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

*(and don't forget to remove your own definition of "cmd"!)*

You can then simply use commands this way:

```
if (cmd === "say") {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGE")) return message.reply("cant use this command");
  let botmessage = args.join(" ");
  message.delete().catch();
  for (var item=0; item<re.length; item++) {
    // whatever there should go in
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks sorry for being late !

Comment: You're welcome, and sorry for beeing late now too ^^'
Did it work?

Comment: Glad to hear that  Wish you the best, and have a nice day 